# Connecting two different database in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to connect two database and establish a relationship between them in tableau. One from sql sever and another from Microsoft excel sheet. How to do that?

I have goggled a lot for that but could not get a suitable answer.

Comment: Sorry man, Data Blending is one of the most basic and advertised features in Tableau. You haven't googled it a lot. The result for your very first phrase has the answer you need

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect two data sources together without Join in Tableau](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909746/connect-two-data-sources-together-without-join-in-tableau)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**You are speaking about Data Blending -**](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#multiple_connections.html)

And for connecting cross database data

[**Cross Database Querying is a Flagship Upgrade to Tableau 10.0**](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/7/integrate-your-data-cross-database-joins-56724)

[image]

**However**, **you cannot use cross-database joins with these below connection types:**

```
Tableau Server
Firebird
Google Analytics
Microsoft Analysis Services
Microsoft PowerPivot
Odata
Oracle Essbase
Salesforce
SAP BW
Splunk
Teradata OLAP Connector
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to connect to each database separately and make sure they have the same column names.  When creating a sheet when you switch between datasources you will see a chain on the linked fields.

Do note that this is not properly joined but is just blended data, it would be best to create another table in your sql database for the excel sheet.